# Typescript: Is there a way to show properties and methods without casting to class type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I wrote this piece of typescript code to replicate a problem I have in my project. I have a base class (in this case "Foo") and lots of other classes which extend from "Foo". The function "instanciateFoos" should be able to instanciate a fooLike class (in this case "Bar") and return it with the correct type. I have lots of very long class names and I would love to have a way to call the function without having to write the class name twice. With my current solution I always have to cast the returned  object into the class which I already passed into the function to make typescript recognize it as an instance of the class. Maybe there is some way to fix this problem using generics or something similar.

```
class Foo
{
    constructor() { }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    talk()
    {
        console.log("Bar");
    }
}

function instanciateFoos(fooLikeClass: typeof Foo)
{
    return new fooLikeClass();
}


let myBar = instanciateFoos(Bar);

myBar.talk();

// Error: Property 'talk' does not exist on type 'Foo'.ts(2339)


let myBar2 = <Bar>initiateFoos(Bar);

myBar2.talk();

// works
```

Comment: To give a better example...
In Unity (C#) you can add components to gameObjects like this:

transform = gameObject.addComponent<Transform>();

Here, the class name is only required once, because of how generics work in C# (or at least I think so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have guessed, given the `generics` tag, you can solve this by making `instantiateFoos` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function:

```
function instantiateFoos<T extends Foo>(fooLikeClass: new () => T) {
  return new fooLikeClass();
}
```

Instead of the `fooLikeClass` parameter being of type `typeof Foo`, we have it be of type `new () => T`, a no-arg [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) which produces instances of type `T`, where `T` is the generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be a subtype of `Foo`.

Now your call works as desired:

```
let myBar = instantiateFoos(Bar); // let myBar: Bar;
myBar.talk(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oFMC2AHALgJ4DC4UmEAIvAOqYCWATgCYAqAFvQHYDmMAvNHyMArpgDc6aMHhcIwkcHzxGACgCUKaAF9Uu1KEgwAQmEZYAHvkxdmMBEjQZ8YEAGsNKKRhlz4ITAA6EHgeVQAiU0Zw9UkMXX0AMxEuJXpZaG55MC58ejBrBwgAHlZLa1t7RAA+VUTEABl6N0xSIwAuaC5MAHdoT35q6FZNJ2hGTHwRRi4u3uh6+CaWtqgNSX0A-GhsQijoQSyXXPzCxAhVKNjoAHob6CjUXajAl3d12-v4NzBCVFQgA)